# How to make a computed field (sum) outside a DataWindow? (PB 11.5)

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

I am trying to feed the sum of a column (`sum(#2 for all)`) into an external SingleLineEdit control (on the same sheet as the DataWindow, but not in it) but I do not know how/where to implement the computation as `sum()` isn't a script "function".

So is it even possible to feed a DataWindow `sum()` out from the DataWindow itself and into a control? If so, how is it done? Will I have to manually calculate the sum with a loop?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a computed field in the datawindow with the sum(#2 for all) function. Give that field a name, like "mySum" or something.  Place that computed field in one of the bands, like the header or footer.

Now, in the event/function script, do a dw.GetItemNumber( 1, "mySum" )

You can use any row number you want, but you're pretty certain to have a row 1 in your result set.

-Paul-

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to calculate without a computed field (`dw.Describe('Evaluate(...)')` *is very versatile*):

```
string expressionText, sumAsText, formattedSum

expressionText = 'sum(#2 for all)'
sumAsText= dw_data.Describe('Evaluate("' + expressionText + '", 0)')

// Formatting of your choice
sle_sum.Text = string(dec(sumAsText), "#,##0.00")
```

/MicKr-